# Buttons inside Table layout not showing up in emulator

Tags: android, kotlin

I have made a simple table layout with buttons. When I try to run it , the emulator doesn't show anything, only a spot! does to anyone happened this problem again?

L**ayout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:gravity="center"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TableRow
    android:layout_marginBottom="3pt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bu1"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="40pt"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3pt"
        android:onClick="buClick" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bu2"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="40pt"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3pt"
        android:onClick="buClick" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bu3"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="40pt"
        android:onClick="buClick" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_marginBottom="3pt"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bu4"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="40pt"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3pt"
        android:onClick="buClick" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bu5"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="40pt"
        android:layout_marginEnd="3pt"
        android:onClick="buClick" />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/bu6"
        android:layout_width="40pt"
        android:layout_height="40pt"
        android:onClick="buClick" />
 </TableRow>   
</TableLayout>
```

and the preview is: [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pUaa.png)

what I did wrong? do I have to do something else? because I try everything

Comment: do you able to see it in real device? or is it specific to emulator only ?, try adding background color to button just to verify, elevations and shadows might not be visible in emulator

Comment: I check your code and run it in emulator everything seems to fine in your there is no issues

Comment: ok i checked on my device and it is working great but not in the emulator, any suggestions?